# Splunk Hapijs json logging issue

Tags: node.js, logging, splunk, hapi.js

I am using splunk, hapijs(Good, GoodConsole, GoodFile) for logging. All my events are properly formated in json and shown in splunk perfectly. But the log which i am manually logged from :

```
  server.log('info', 'Preparing to start server for environment ' + process.env.NODE_ENV);
  server.log('info', 'Server running at: ' + server.info.uri);
```

These log are not formatted properly in splunk.

```
{"event":"log","timestamp":1445829225256,"tags":["info"],"data":"Preparing to start server for environment local","pid":17232}
{"event":"log","timestamp":1445829225265,"tags":["info"],"data":"Server running at: http://MyMachine.local:9000","pid":17332}
{"event":"log","timestamp":1445829225268,"tags":["info"],"data":"Communicating with Other server at: http://10.7.219.18:80”,”pid":17332}
```

Splunk consider them as 1 event and I am not able to query on this.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question for someone who doesn't know Splunk or what it does? What do they logs look like? How should they look?

Comment: @MattHarrison is cloud solution for servers logs. we can do analysis on these log easily.. more details at http://www.splunk.com/

Comment: @AbhishekNalwaya I'm not sure I understand your question, can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you manually added the logs. But to tell Splunk about the sourcetype you have to configure that in props.conf. I see no reason that if you send json and properly have setting it should not be able to extract the fields.

> `[mysourcetype]
>
>   KV_MODE = json`

Answer (score 0):

It worked, I have to tell splunk to break the event if he find space and {

updated ->
 vi $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/props.conf

```
SHOULD_LINEMERGE = false
LINE_BREAKER = ^\{
```